# onClick event won't work in my React code

Tags: reactjs, events

I have an onClick event inside render() that won't work, I've tried (clearly not) everything.

What am I doing wrong?

```
render() {

const Card = ({backgroundColor, id, state}) =>{  
    const style = {
        width: '100px',
        height:'100px',
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        key: id,
        state: state,
    }
    return <div style={style} />
}

const finalCards = this.state.cards.map((n) =>(
  <Card backgroundColor={n.hiddenColor} key={n.id} state={n.state} onClick={() => alert('clicked')} />
));

return (
  <div className="App">
      {finalCards}
  </div>
);
```

}
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Card is a separate component, you should keep it declare it outside of your render method.

But the problem is that you're passing an `onClick` function to a component but you're not hooking up that `onClick` function to the HTML element (in this case the `<div />`).

This should work

```
const Card = ({backgroundColor, id, state, onClick}) =>{  
    const style = {
        width: '100px',
        height:'100px',
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        key: id,
        state: state,
    }
    return <div style={style} onClick={onClick} />
}
```